# kafka KStream - topology to take n-second counts

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream of JSON objects that Im keying on a hash of a few values. Im hoping to count by key in n-second (10? 60?) intervals and use these values to do some pattern analysis.

My topology: `K->aggregateByKey(n seconds)->process()`

In the `process - init()` step Ive called `ProcessorContent.schedule(60 * 1000L)` in hopes of having the `.punctuate()` get called. From here I would loop through the values in an internal hash and act accordingly.

Im seeing values come through the aggregation step and hit the `process()` function but the `.punctuate()` is never getting called.

---

### Code:

```
KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> opxLines = kStreamBuilder.stream(TOPIC);

KStream<String, String> mapped = opxLines.map(new ReMapper());

KTable<Windowed<String>, String> ktRtDetail = mapped.aggregateByKey(
            new AggregateInit(),
            new OpxAggregate(),
            TimeWindows.of("opx_aggregate", 60000));

ktRtDetail.toStream().process(new ProcessorSupplier<Windowed<String>, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public Processor<Windowed<String>, String> get() {
                                 return new AggProcessor();
                            }
                       });
    
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, streamsConfig);

kafkaStreams.start();
```

**AggregateInit()** returns null.

I guess I can do the `.punctuate()` equivalent with a simple timer but I'd like to know why this code isn't working the way I'd hope.

Comment: What is your time semantics (event time processing time?) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251997/kafka-kstream-using-abstractprocessor-with-a-window about punctuate internals.

Comment: It's explored a bit further [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535201/kafka-problems-with-timestampextractor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to an improper setup for the kafka cluster. After changing the *file descriptor count* to a much higher value than the default (1024 -> 65535) this seems to be working per spec.