# Kafka - problems with TimestampExtractor

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:0.10.0.1`

I'm attempting to work with a time series based stream that doesn't seem to be triggering a `KStream.Process()` to trigger ("punctuate"). (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500383/kafka-kstream-topology-to-take-n-second-counts) for reference)

In a `KafkaStreams` config I'm passing in this param (among others):

```
config.put(
  StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG,
  EventTimeExtractor.class.getName());
```

Here, `EventTimeExtractor` is a custom timestamp extractor (that implements `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor`) to extract the timestamp information from JSON data.

I would expect this to call my object (derived from `TimestampExtractor`) when each new record is pulled in. The stream in question is 2 * 10^6 records / minute. I have `punctuate()` set to 60 seconds and it never fires. I know the data passes this span very frequently since its pulling old values to catch up.

In fact it never gets called at all.

- Is this the wrong approach to setting timestamps on KStream records?
- Is this the wrong way to declare this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is another case of issues at the broker level. I went and rebuilt the cluster using instances with more CPU and RAM. Now I'm getting the results I expected.

Note to distant observer(s): if your **KStream** app is behaving strangely take a look at your brokers and make sure they aren't stuck in GC and have plenty of 'headroom' for file handles, RAM, etc.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500383/kafka-kstream-topology-to-take-n-second-counts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8):

**Update Nov 2017:** Kafka Streams in Kafka 1.0 now supports `punctuate()` with both stream-time and with processing-time (wall clock time) behavior. So you can pick whichever behavior you prefer.

Your setup seems correct to me.

What you need to be aware of:  As of Kafka 0.10.0, the `punctuate()` method operates on *stream-time* (by default, i.e. based on the default timestamp extractor, stream-time will mean event-time).  And the stream-time is only advanced when new data records are coming in, and how much the stream-time is advanced is determined by the associated timestamps of these new records.

For example:

- Let's assume you have set `punctuate()` to be called every 1 minute = `60 * 1000` (note: 1 minute of *stream-time*).  Now, if it happens that no data is being received for the next 5 minutes, `punctuate()` will not be called at all -- even though you might expect it to be called 5 times.  Why?  Again, because `punctuate()` depends on stream-time, and the stream-time is only advanced based on newly received data records.

Might this be causing the behavior you are seeing?

Looking ahead: There's already a ongoing discussion in the Kafka project on how to make `punctuate()` more flexible, e.g. to have trigger it not only based on `stream-time` (which defaults to `event-time`) but also based on `processing-time`.

Comment: Are the records that your application is reading containing embedded timestamps at all?  Are you using, for example, a 0.9 Kafka cluster or older version?

Comment: All server components are from the confluent repo. Installed within the last few weeks. The records do contain a timestamp field (records are JSON encoded). I wouldn't expect kafka to pick out this field hence the use of 'the extractor' (sounds v ominous)

Comment: Im thinking something is up with said kafka cluster. 5 server and 1 zk all running on AWS. Im trying to push data from 3 threads and barely getting 1M / min. Adding a second process (separate machine) *reduces* the total throughput. Network interfaces are all < ~30%. Load is 1-2. These are all 8 core / 32G machines. It should be screaming fast. Topic has 6 partitions with rep-factor 2.

Comment: Note to some distant observer: be sure to set the **file descriptor count** to something practical. On centos/aws the default seems to be 1024 which isn't enough even for a small setup (increased to 65535). This was a big issue with my cluster.

Comment: But your problem still exists, even after increasing `nofile`?

Comment: That's correct. No change. Im getting more reliable callbacks from the `.punctuate` call but there are a slew of separate questions about that. At least one thing is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems to be correct. Compare pargraph **"Timestamp Extractor (timestamp.extractor):"** in http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/streams/developer-guide.html#optional-configuration-parameters

Not sure, why your custom timestamp extractor is not used. Have a look into `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask`. In the constructor there should be something like

```java
TimestampExtractor timestampExtractor1 = (TimestampExtractor)config.getConfiguredInstance("timestamp.extractor", TimestampExtractor.class);
```

Check if your custom extractor is picked up there or not...

Comment: I put some logging into the `.extract()` function and it's never getting hit. The constructor for the class is though.

Comment: Can you share your data and/or code? matthias@confluent.io