# Kafka streams 1.0: processing timeout with high max.poll.interval.ms and session.timeout.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using a stateless processor using Kafka streams 1.0 with kafka broker 1.0.1

The problem is, the CustomProcessor get closed every few seconds, which resulted in rebalance signal, I am using the following configs:

`session.timeout.ms=15000`

`heartbeat.interval.ms=3000` // set it to 1/3 session.timeout

`max.poll.interval.ms=Integer.MAX_VALUE` // make it that large as I am doing a intensive computational operations that might take up to 10 mins processing 1 kafka message (NLP operations)

`max.poll.records=1`

despite this configuration and my understanding of how kafka timeout configurations work, I see the consumer rebalancing every few seconds.

I already went through the below article and other stackoverflow questions. about how to tune the long time operations and avoid very long session timeout that will make failure detection so late, however I still see unexpected behavior, unless I misunderstand something.

[KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)

[Diff between session.timeout.ms and max.poll.interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730126/difference-between-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms-for-kafka-0-10-0)

[Kafka kstreams processing timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232395/kafka-kstreams-processing-timeouts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich%20_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

For the consumer environment setup, I have 8 machines each 16 code, and consuming from 1 topic with 100 partitions, I am following what practice  this confluent [doc here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html#examples) recommends.

Any pointers?

Comment: What is the root cause for the rebalance? Can you clarify the dependency between closing a processor and the rebalance? It seems, one happens first (root cause) triggering the other one. Did you check the logs?

Comment: When I see `processor.close()`, I immediately see the few seconds pause (which is roughly the `session.timeout.ms duration`) and I see rebalance happens, application logs are fine, no exceptions or anything that will exit the process() method uncleanly

Comment: From my understanding @MatthiasJ.Sax that the close() should not be called in the normal flow of the application, in other words, the .close() is not called with every message for example like the init() method, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, init() and close() should only be called when a partitions is assigned/revoked. close() might also be called if an exception is thrown and a task fails. Thus, it's puzzling to me what actually happens for the case you describe. If `session.timeout.ms` hits, there should be a log entry on the broker that host the group coordinator of the consumer group. Maybe DEBUG logs show more information?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax I will try to check the broker logs and enable the DEBUG logs and will post the updates.

Comment: I enabled debug log level on broker, and the logs are very very noisy, do you know which log I should expect or grep for?

Comment: This is what I got from more looking at the logs `DEBUG [SocketServer brokerId=1] Connection with /X.X.X.X disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)
 at `

Comment: Here is the rest of the above log `org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:545)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:483)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412)
 at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:551)
 at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:468)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: A disconnect should not close the processor -- really unclear to me what's happening there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. after lots of debugging and enable verbose logging for both kafka streams client and the broker, it turned out to 2 things:

1. There is a critical bug in streams 1.0.0 ([HERE](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6366)), so I upgraded my client version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
2. I update the value of the consumer property `default.deserialization.exception.handler` from `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler` to `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`.

After the above 2 changes, everything went so perfect with no restarts, I am using grafana to monitor the restarts, and for the past 48 hours, there is no single restart happened.

I might do more troubleshooting to make sure which of the 2 items above make the real fix, but I am on a hurry to deploy to production, so if anybody is intrested to start from there, go ahead, else, once I got time will do the further analysis and update the answer!

So happy to get this fixed!!!